# Why are type variables of non-static inner classes specified in generic signatures?

Tags: java, generics

When I define a type:

```
class Bar<S> {
  /* non-static */ class Foo<U extends Foo<U>> { }
}
```

The Java compiler generates a generic signature as the following for the created type:

```
<U:Lfoo/Bar<TS;>.Foo<TU;>;>Ljava/lang/Object;
```

In case that the inner type is defined to be static, the generic signature is instead defined as:

```
<U:Lfoo/Bar$Foo<TU;>;>Ljava/lang/Object;
```

The difference being that the type variables of `Foo`'s outer class `Bar` are also stored in the signature. I am now wondering why the Java compiler would add this information in the signature in this way. I fail to understand why it would make a difference for defining `U` appropriately since `U` is in no way dependant on `S` or the outer class. What ambigouity is the Java compiler trying to resolve?

I would like to know an example for when this information is actually used for resolving a type. Also, I noticed that the Java reflection API does not return a different result for the static or non-static case.

Comment: 'Non-static inner' is a tautology.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your assumption is wrong. What you are seeing in the (JVM) type signature is `U`'s upper bound. That upper bound is `Foo<U>` or, when fully qualified, `foo.Bar<S>.Foo<U>`. Try denoting `Foo<U>` outside the scope of `Bar`. javac will yell at you. ;)

```
class Bar<S> {
  /* non-static */ class Foo<U extends Foo<U>> {}
}

Bar.Foo<?> foo = null; // error
Bar<String>.Foo<?> foo = null; // fine
```

**Edit**: The `TS;` you are seeing is not the type parameter, it's the type argument. Fully qualify the bound and use another argument to make it apparent:

```
class Baz {}

class Bar<S> {
  /* non-static */ class Foo<U extends Bar<Baz>.Foo<U>> {}
}
```

Comment: I am aware of this. But why is this additional information put inside the generic signature? It could already be inferred from the class file. It feels redundant to put the names of the type variables there. I am wondering if this is really redunandant and just a short-cut for javac or if this information does actually contain additional information.

Comment: It puts the fully qualified type in the file. The fully qualified type includes the outer type. No shortcut possible (at this place imports or scopes are no longer relevant).

Comment: @RafaelWinterhalter I edited the answer to, hopefully, clear up the confusion.

Comment: @BenSchulz I did actually not know that the inner argument was implicit for the generic argument. Thank you for the example, this is what I wanted to know.